# stack exchange data explorer on previous data dumps

Tags: discussion

Can I use stack exchange data explorer to extract data on a previous data dump, say of year 2011 ? 
Can anyone suggest how I could go about it ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The data explorer only contains the most recent database, and does not have archived former databases. You can [download the torrent for a past dump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent), but I don't know of any way to analyze that dump using the data explorer (you can do it with your own SQL though, I understand that the structure is very similar).

Comment: I am not sure of this , but can you suggest if stack apps would work in this case.

Comment: @user, no, it wouldn't. The only way you will get the data is by downloading it and querying it yourself. You can turn that in to an app if you want afterwards, but it isn't going to be doable without downloading the torrent of the dump first.